# Should I use python on windows or cygwin?

Tags: python

I have a windows 7 computer and was wondering whether to use the windows version of python or the one in cygwin. Especially with regard to modules that do not come pre-installed, which one is easier to install new modules?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Presumably that's exactly what he means by "the windows version of python".

Comment: @abarnert Oops. Meant to respond to Joel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

ActivePython works just fine on Win7.  Cygwin would add an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: What's the difference between ActivePython and CPython?

Comment: @user2836556: ActivePython is a commercial (but free for some use cases) distribution built around CPython. It comes with some extra packages pre-installed (which also automatically get updated if you update to a later ActivePython version), and some minor configuration tweaks, and optionally professional support contracts.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you want to use it for, far more than which one is easier to install new modules.

If you plan on running scripts from within the cygwin bash shell, or to access files within the cygwin subtree of your directory, to WSGI to a cygwin web server, etc., you probably want the Cygwin version.

If you plan on running scripts from within the cmd.exe DOS prompt, or to access files in special locations under your home directory, or to WSGI to a native web server, you probably want the native version.

---

If you really do want to know which one is easier to install new modules for… the answer is that it depends.

If you want pre-built binary packages, Cygwin only has a handful of them, while Cristoph Gohkle has [a ton](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) of packages for native Python.

If you want to build packages yourself (manually, or just using `pip` automatically), and you need any packages that use C extension modules, you'll need to set up a compiler, which is a bit easier in Cygwin, but not all *that* hard in either.

There are a few modules out there that aren't developed or tested for cygwin, and will guess your platform as linux or Windows or something else wrong, or just make inappropriate assumptions.

There are also a few modules that only work on POSIX, that do happen to work with cygwin but not with native Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Both work, it all comes down to which you're more comfortable using; windows or cygwin.